# Translucency issue with iPad running 7.0.4

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios-simulator

In my universal app I use translucent Navigation bars and I allow the content to go under the bars and have that nice blur effect.

While testing the app in my iPad 3 running iOS 7.0.4 I've noticed that the Navigation bars are not translucent any more, but transparent, without the blur effect. Please look at the screenshot below.

[image: iPad running 7.0.4]

The same app running in the iPad simulator running iOS 7.0.3 is working as expected... Please look at the second screen shot

[image: iPad simulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third-gen iPad doesn’t support blurring on iOS 7—only the iPad mini and fourth-gen iPad and onwards do. It looks like you might be using a color with a non-1 alpha value as your navigation bar’s background color—you might try replacing that with a fully opaque color. If that’s not the case or doesn’t work, you may be stuck disabling the translucency on older devices (i.e. the third-gen iPad and the iPad 2).

Comment: I'm using iPad R
with toolBar and the same...
code example:

`UIToolbar* blurredView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [blurredView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [blurredView setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHex:@"32353A"]];
    blurredView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view insertSubview:blurredView atIndex:0];`
On lower versions works.
Acording to your answear on iPad R should be working...